# Load angular directive in view, based on $scope value

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, scope, directive

I have a directive defined as

```
Application.Directives.directive('listview', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        templateUrl: 'directives/listview/view.html'
    };
});
```

And then want to include it from the main view like this

```
<div class="{{directiveName}}">
</div>
```

where directiveName equals "listview". However, it does not work. It generates the below code, but the listview directive does not get loaded

```
<div class="listview">
</div>
```

Yet, when I type the above generated code directly into the main template, it *does* load the directive. How come? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a way. What you'd want is something like this

```
<div {{directiveNameInScope}}></div>
```

But again, that doesn't work. So I created a directive to do it for you. It works like

```
<div loaddirective="directiveNameInScope"></div>
```

where the loaddirective directive looks like

```
Application.Directives.directive('loaddirective', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { loaddirective : "=loaddirective" },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            var value = $scope.loaddirective;
            if (value) {
                // Load the directive and make it reactive
                $element.html("<div "+value+"></div>");
                $compile($element.contents())($scope);
            }
        },
        replace: true
    };
});
```

I put it up on github here: https://github.com/willemmulder/loaddirective